# How to create a war file from a jython WSGI web application

Tags: jython, war, wsgi, keystone

I would like to deploy a WSGI ([keystone](http://late.am/post/2011/11/27/keystone-a-simple-python-web-framework)) web application, running with jython 2.5.2, as a war file to a java servlet application server (specifically glassfish).

How can I create a war file from my keystone web application (or any WSGI app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I found this.

http://opensource.xhaus.com/projects/modjy/wiki/ModjyWarPackaging

That showed how to create a war file from any WSGI app (which keystone is).

Answer (score 0):

Creating an empty django project, creating a war file from it and inspecting the war file contents like so also helps.

1. Install jython
2. Install setuptools
3. jython (jython install dir)/bin/easy_install django # currently version 1.4.1
4. jython (jython install dir)/bin/easy_install django_jython
5. jython (jython install dir)/bin/django_admin.py startproject emptyProj
6. cd emptyProj
7. Edit emptyProj/emptyProj/settings.py and put ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX=STATIC_URL at the end of the file and add 'doj', to the INSTALLED_APPS tuple.
8. jython manage.py startapp emptyApp
9. jython manage.py war
10. mkdir tmp
11. mv emptyProj.war tmp
12. cd tmp
13. unzip emptyProj.war
14. Manually inspect the war file structure